# Write decoded text string as binary in c++

Tags: c++, binary

So I have some decoded text which I have to write as binary in a new file.
I came up with this code but it writes it as a decoded text instead of binary

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <locale> 
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream outputFile;
    outputfile.open("binary.dat");  
    ifstream file("binary.dat",  ios::binary); 
    outputfile <<"68656C6C6F20776F726C64";
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by binary? Do you want it to write the binary representation (i.e. 01011010111010)?

Comment: I assume you mean the actual octets. I.e. 0x68, 0x65, etc.I.e. you need a translator that builds bytes from hex encoding (and that right there are some search-terms worthy of google-fu). You also needs a *much* better description of the problem being solved, and at least an attempt at solving it beside dumping a string literal to an output file. Unrelated, `file` appears to have no useful purpose in this whatsoever.

Comment: @WhozCraig based on the amount of includes at the top as well, I'd reasonably say that OP is probably using it somewhere down the line, but simply excluded that code from this post

Comment: Please be more specific about the results you want. _Everything_'s binary in a sense. You have to explain what you're trying to do. Did you want to write, in sequence, the bytes who have hex-pair representation 0x68, 0x65, 0x6C etc to the file?

Comment: I meat that 68 65 6C 6C 6F 20 77 6F 72 6C 64 are supposed to be the bytes that I'm trying to write, but if I open the file in HxD it shows it on the left as a decoded text instead of showing me the correspondent of my bytes (hello world)

Comment: In that case you need to parse the string into numbers and write those to a file. But this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - where does the string come from? Maybe data is being converted into a string that could just be used directly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the file in binary mode to write binary data

`outputfile.open("binary.dat", ofstream::binary)`

**Note**: This is assuming you are intending to simply write the binary representation of your text string, rather than treat your string as hexadecimal values as was mentioned in the comments

Comment: Ok it works, I got what I was searching for thank you!